# React-Native: How do use react native fabric?

Tags: react-native, google-fabric

I use https://github.com/corymsmith/react-native-fabric, https://fabric.io/home
library, I have done follow tutorial. But I can't create app on https://fabric.io/home after I run app on Android emulator. Please help me!

Comment: Please see how to make questions.

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. We don't currently have official support for React Native apps. It's likely that we're missing a build event in addition to the run in order to activate your app. Enabling debug mode https://docs.fabric.io/android/fabric/advanced-settings/debugging.html and doing a clean, build and then run of your app may help.

Answer (score 0):

Just integrate Fabric in both of your separate apps in android and ios dirs. Follow this instructions to each platform and you will have two apps in Fabric account.
[Fabric Crashlyticas Install](https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/install)